# Placing the Same QImage Multiple Times in a Loop

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I am trying to build some sort of media player. Currently, the basic functions of the media player work and there is a video progress bar that show where in the video they are and how long. This progress bar is a slider and what I want to do is place tick marks on this progress bar (like bookmarks but for videos) based on user input. I have this working as a QList. However, when I save the user input into a text file containing the tick mark locations and the video location. It loads everything contained in  the file properly besides the tick markers which are just QImages. It only loads the last tick marker

Currently, the code is a for loop that takes the positions listed calculates the position the tick marker must go on the progress bar and places it there.

Shown below is the portion of code that is related to this issue:

```
int slider_xpos = ui->VideoProgressSlider->x();
int slider_ypos = ui->VideoProgressSlider->y();
int slider_width = ui->VideoProgressSlider->width();


while(!Bookmark_Placement.empty())
{
    //New Bookmark is initialized 
    Bookmarker_Label = new QLabel(this);
    Bookmark = new QImage();
    Bookmark->load("UI_Elements/Bookmark.png");

    //Bookmark's image is scaled down
    int scaled_width = Bookmark->width()/64;
    int scaled_height = Bookmark->height()/64;
    QImage *Bookmark_Scaled = new QImage(Bookmark->scaled(scaled_width,Bookmark->height(),Qt::KeepAspectRatio));
    Bookmarker_Label->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(*Bookmark_Scaled));

    //Takes the Bookmark's position off of QList
    int Bookmark_Position = Bookmark_Placement.last();
    Bookmark_Placement.removeLast();

    //Places Bookmark in the proper position
    double offset = ((double)Bookmark_Position/(double)Bookmark_Count)*(double)slider_width;
    int Bookmarker_Label_xpos= slider_xpos + (int)offset;
    Bookmarker_Label->setGeometry(Bookmarker_Label_xpos,slider_ypos - scaled_height,scaled_width,scaled_height);

    Bookmarker_Label->show();
}
```

Comment: I suggest you show us your code rather than trying to describe it. It is very unlikely we can help you debug your code based on a description.

Comment: [mcve] or it didn't happen

Comment: @ypnos I have added the code.

Comment: You should print out (qDebug) the parameters passed to setGeometry to see how the labels are positioned.

Comment: @tunglt For 6 tick marks that were loaded from the file, it displayed the following positions on qDebug: 
4277
68432
21996
14664
7332
0
which seem to be correct. Seeing that an individual tick mark is placed correctly but inside the loop only the last tick mark that is created is displayed.

Comment: Could you provide (edit your question) how Bookmark_count is calculated?

Comment: @tunglt The bookmark count is just the frame count of the video and that what the progress bar keeps a track of what frame the video is currently on.

Comment: I doubt offset is not correctly computed, so that labels are positioned outside of the widget, could you show up the related information? (offset, slider_xpos, slider_ypos, scaled_height of each Bookmark created).

Comment: can you store your Bookmarker_Label  in a vector without the memory leak currently you have one pointer for all your instances

Comment: @tunglt Thank for your help, your assumption was correct the offset was being calculated incorrectly because the frame count was not set properly.